# Why does Flow assume this function returns a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, typechecking

I have the following code: a function which returns an option from an array. The options could be strings or regexes, and the return value will follow suit.

```js
const pick = (options: Array<string | RegExp>): string | RegExp =>
  options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

const myOptions = ['hello', 'goodbye']
const randomId: string = pick(myOptions);
```

This raises this error:

> Cannot assign `pick(...)` to `randomId` because  `RegExp` [1] is incompatible with  string [2].Flow(incompatible-type)

Why is this?

Comment: `pick` can return either a string or regexp. You can't assign that to a string variable, because it might return a regexp.

Comment: Is there a way I can convince Flow that it will return a string if I pass an array of string, other than two separate function definitions for the two cases?

Comment: How does it know that `myOptions` will always be an array of strings?

Comment: I would be amazed, if flow didn't have generics. In TS you would use `const pick = <T>(options: T[]) => /*...*/;`, there should be something very similar for flow. (or if you want to limit, `<T extends string | RegExp>` as generic parameter). Looking at docs, syntax for flow seems to be almost identical

Comment: @Barmar because it's a `const`? :)

Comment: Also, I don't think that `Array<string | RegExp>` means that the array contains either only strings or only regexps. That type also includes arrays containing a mixture of them.

Comment: The declaration of `pick` doesn't say that the result type will be the same as the types of the array elements.

Comment: FlowType does have generics: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, building from the comments, there are several issues here:

- the type signature of the array is "Array of things that are either strings or regexs", not "Array of strings or array of regexes"
- Flow doesn't know that the return type matches the provided type, so it's possible the function returns a regex, which can't be stored in a string.

Using a generic, we can redefine the function like this:

```
const pick = <T>(options: Array<T>): T =>
  options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
```

This works fine.